# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' is defined

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am getting below error when trying to run the Spring Batch code. I have configured JobRepository and JobLauncher and also configured the Job. When running via main method getting the below error

Code

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.YY.INT:1527/TEST" />
        <property name="username" value="TEST_USER" />
        <property name="password" value="BGFFFF" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="ORACLE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
```

Error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.SendCustomerApp.main(SendCustomerApp.java:27)
```

Main Method:

```
public class SendCustomerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/ABC_context.xml");

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean("ABCJob");

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("EXIT STATUS :: "+execution.getStatus());

        System.out.println("DONE !!");
    }
}
```

**ABC_Job.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.YY.INT:1527/TEST" />
        <property name="username" value="TEST_USER" />
        <property name="password" value="BGFFFF" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="ORACLE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="billDataBatchJob">
    ..........
    ..........
    ...........
    .............
    ..............
    </batch:job>

</beans>
```

I enabled the logs and saw the below logs

```
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:127 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:317 - Resolved classpath location [META-INF/spring/ABC.job.xml] to resources []
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG XmlBeanDefinitionReader:224 - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:META-INF/spring/ABC.job.xml]
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:615 - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@51016012: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a968a59: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:728 - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@2286778]
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:752 - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@3e9b1010]
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:745 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a968a59: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:779 - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@6ddf90b0]
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2018-06-25 15:16:25 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:91 - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.CustomerFileGenerationMain.main(CustomerFileGenerationMain.java:17)
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack error  trace ?

Comment: Can you please paste the whole ABC_context.xml ?

Comment: @mr.cool - Details has been added.... Ishant - This is the complete stack trace.. I may need to add logger if you need minute details

Comment: I don't see you calling refresh: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh--

Comment: @Michael  could you please add code snippet? This will help for the beginner like me

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using maven? I've run into some similar problems with maven not building projects correctly, leading to beans getting left out and similar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the below by using the FileSystemXMlApplication context. I strongly believe the project structure of maven project which I am using is not correct or its using both Boot and MainMethod.

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");

        String[] springConfig = { "C:\\XXXX\\src\\main\\resources\\META-INF\\spring\\XXXXX-job.xml" };

        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("XXXJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a project to test your code and everything goes well. I just change dataSource bean properties to connect to an h2-db instead of Oracle. about your problem consider, you pasted ABC_Job.xml content but in your code, you refer to ABC_context.xml, maybe this is your problem. by the way, if you add proper logger and set log level to debug, you can see which beans created by spring, and you can trace your beans to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I added loggers properly but still its not printing the loggers at all.. Also I am already loading ABC_context.xml, but why its not working not sure.. Something related to Project structure ?

Comment: Would you provide more information about your project setup

Comment: Your update clearly show there is no bean definition in ABC.job.xml:
Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:META-INF/spring/ABC.job.xml]

Comment: Right, but why its not loading any beans? So weird ? To me it looks like XML file is not getting loaded properly..    Resolved classpath location [META-INF/spring/ABC-job.xml] to resources []

Comment: The file spring try to load is ABC.job.xml refering to log not ABC-job.xml